# 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable - django-import-export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I have a django app I am working on and in the admin page, I'd like to be able to export a model's list view as csv, xls and multiple other file formats. I'm using `django-import-export` package for that. I have installed and added it to my installed apps in settings.py.

In my `models.py` I have..

```
class Student(models.Model):
  firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  middlename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  admission_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  grade = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}'
```

My `admin.py` file

```
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'admission_number', 'grade', 'joined')
  list_filter = ('grade', 'joined',)


admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
```

To handle the import and export functionality, I have created a file in the same directory called resource.py where I have the following `django-import-export` specific code.

```
from import_export import resources
from import_exports.fields import Field
from .models import Student

class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):
  full_name = Field(column_name='name')

  class Meta:
    model = Student
    fields = ('full_name', 'admission_number', 'grade', 'joined')
    widgets = {
      'joined': { 'format': '%d/%m/%Y'},
    }

  def dehydrate_full_name(self, student):
    return f'{student.firstname} {student.middlename} {student.lastname}'
```

As you can see from the above code, I have created a new field `full_name` which I want to hold the full name of a student under the column `name` and I'd like it exported that way.

I would like to be able to export the data via an admin action and after reading through django-import-export documentation, I updated my admin.py file..

```
# Added these imports
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from .resource import StudentResource

class StudentExportAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
    resource_class = StudentResource

class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'admission_number', 'grade', 'joined')
  list_filter = ('grade', 'joined',)


admin.site.register(Student, StudentAdmin)
admin.site.register(StudentExportAdmin)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Someone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change according to this,

```
class StudentAdmin(ImportExportActionModelAdmin):
  resource_class = StudentResource
  list_display = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'admission_number', 'grade', 'joined')
  list_filter = ('grade', 'joined',)



admin.site.register(Student,StudentAdmin)
```

remove this line, as `import-export` will automatically place it in the `admin` panel according to the `resources` you have used.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Just to clarify though, could you please tell me if the code in my resource.py file is proper? The full_name part at least.

Comment: The solution above successfully got rid of the error but in the admin, there is no such action as export as? What am I missing?